# Classic ASP - display records from databse in the table Week-wise or month-wise

Tags: sql, asp-classic, vbscript, sql-server-2000, ado

I'm using asp code i.e classic ASP and SQL server 2000 in this process to display records from database into a table.
I have two links called week-wise and month-wise . 
when the user clicks on this link he will see the data week-wise or month-wise assuming the database have a date field which stores all the dates, when the record is inserted.

So far i'm able to display records present in the table for that particular user. How can i display his/her records WEEK or MONTH wise.

this is the query that I have use

```
<%
    sql="select SUM(grand_total) as total from order_details where emp_number='"&request.QueryString("no")&"'"
    rs.open sql,con,1,2
    do while not rs.eof

        rs.movenext
    loop
    rs.close
%>
```

this particular query displays records of that particular result...

Comment: Check out [How to group by week with MSSQL](http://www.sqlhacks.com/Dates/Group-By-Week) and you should be able to adapt something for monthly grouping as well.

Comment: Something like `... AND [date column] BETWEEN '2012-04-01' AND '2012-04-30'`?

Comment: @SalmanA no, do not use BETWEEN... https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx & https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mishandling-date-range-queries.aspx

Comment: @Aaron: It kind of depends on what your `date column` contains and how you interpret its content.

Comment: @SalmanA Since BETWEEN is only valid in a few scenarios (e.g. a DATE column in 2008, whereas this user is using SQL Server 2000, or a case where you absolutely know 100% that there can't be any time information - a constraint helps), I don't think it's good practice to ever use BETWEEN. Why use something that requires extra context and knowledge by all readers, when you could use >= and < which will always work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select
emp_number,
datepart(year, order_date),
datepart(month, order_date),
datepart(wk, order_date),
sum(grand_total)
from order_details
group by
emp_number,
datepart(year, order_date),
datepart(month, order_date),
datepart(wk, order_date)
order by 1, 2, 3, 4
```

And I'd consider using [Prepared Statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905910%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: yr code works fine ..but m confused about the value my WEEK column is returning value is **20** does it mean that 20 weeks ...and **order by 1,2,3,4** what does it mean..can you explain....Thanks for yr reply...

Comment: @Mckenzi - `ORDER BY 1, 2, 3, 4`, that's just references to the first to fourth column in the `SELECT` list. As for the `WK` (week), that's the 20th week of the year.